# Error: TransportError 400, when Django-Haystack search with SQ

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

Using

```
django-haystack==2.4.0
Elasticsearch 1.6.0
```

Getting `TransportError 400` when:

```
from haystack.query import SQ

if self.cleaned_data['q']:
    term = self.cleaned_data['q']
    sqs = sqs.filter(SQ(title=term)|SQ(designation=term)|SQ(skills=term))
```

but below code working without any error:

```
if self.cleaned_data['q']:
    term = self.cleaned_data['q']
    sqs = sqs.filter(title=term)
```

java stack trace:

> Failed to query Elasticsearch using '( OR (title:(python) OR
>   designation:(python)))': TransportError(400,
>   u'SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all
>   shards failed; shardFailures
>   {[1uj2PNSRQQWzaZRUFpuEdQ][haystack_job][0]:
>   SearchParseException[[haystack_job][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse
>   Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter":
>   {"terms": {"django_ct": ["peeldb.jobpost"]}}, "query":
>   {"query_string": {"query": "( OR (title:(python) OR
>   designation:(python)))", "default_operator": "OR", "default_field":
>   "text", "auto_generate_phrase_queries": true, "analyze_wildcard":
>   true}}}}, "from": 0, "size": 1}]]]; nested:
>   QueryParsingException[[haystack_job] Failed to parse query [( OR
>   (title:(python) OR designation:(python)))]]; nested:
>   ParseException[Cannot parse \'( OR (title:(python) OR
>   designation:(python)))\': Encountered "  "OR "" at line 1, column
>   2.\nWas expecting one of:\n     ...\n    "+" ...\n    "-" ...\n     ...\n    "(" ...\n    "*" ...\n     ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n     ...\n     ...\n 
>   "[" ...\n    "{" ...\n     ...\n     ...\n    "*" ...\n 
>   ]; nested: ParseException[Encountered "  "OR "" at line 1, column
>   2.\nWas expecting one of:\n     ...\n    "+" ...\n    "-" ...\n     ...\n    "(" ...\n    "*" ...\n     ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n     ...\n     ...\n 
>   "[" ...\n    "{" ...\n     ...\n     ...\n    "*" ...\n 
>   ]; }{[1uj2PNSRQQWzaZRUFpuEdQ][haystack_job][1]:
>   SearchParseException[[haystack_job][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse
>   Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter":
>   {"terms": {"django_ct": ["peeldb.jobpost"]}}, "query":
>   {"query_string": {"query": "( OR (title:(python) OR
>   designation:(python)))", "default_operator": "OR", "default_field":
>   "text", "auto_generate_phrase_queries": true, "analyze_wildcard":
>   true}}}}, "from": 0, "size": 1}]]]; nested:
>   QueryParsingException[[haystack_job] Failed to parse query [( OR
>   (title:(python) OR designation:(python)))]]; nested:
>   ParseException[Cannot parse \'( OR (title:(python) OR
>   designation:(python)))\': Encountered "  "OR "" at line 1, column
>   2.\nWas expecting one of:\n     ...\n    "+" ...\n    "-" ...\n     ...\n    "(" ...\n    "*" ...\n     ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n     ...\n     ...\n 
>   "[" ...\n    "{" ...\n     ...\n     ...\n    "*" ...\n 
>   ]; nested: ParseException[Encountered "  "OR "" at line 1, column
>   2.\nWas expecting one of:\n     ...\n    "+" ...\n    "-" ...\n     ...\n    "(" ...\n    "*" ...\n     ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n     ...\n     ...\n 
>   "[" ...\n    "{" ...\n     ...\n     ...\n    "*" ...\n 
>   ]; }{[1uj2PNSRQQWzaZRUFpuEdQ][haystack_job][2]:
>   SearchParseException[[haystack_job][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse
>   Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter":
>   {"terms": {"django_ct": ["peeldb.jobpost"]}}, "query":
>   {"query_string": {"query": "( OR (title:(python) OR
>   designation:(python)))", "default_operator": "OR", "default_field":
>   "text", "auto_generate_phrase_queries": true, "analyze_wildcard":
>   true}}}}, "from": 0, "size": 1}]]]; nested:
>   QueryParsingException[[haystack_job] Failed to parse query [( OR
>   (title:(python) OR designation:(python)))]]; nested:
>   ParseException[Cannot parse \'( OR (title:(python) OR
>   designation:(python)))\': Encountered "  "OR "" at line 1, column
>   2.\nWas expecting one of:\n     ...\n    "+" ...\n    "-" ...\n     ...\n    "(" ...\n    "*" ...\n     ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n     ...\n     ...\n 
>   "[" ...\n    "{" ...\n     ...\n     ...\n    "*" ...\n 
>   ]; nested: ParseException[Encountered "  "OR "" at line 1, column
>   2.\nWas expecting one of:\n     ...\n    "+" ...\n    "-" ...\n     ...\n    "(" ...\n    "*" ...\n     ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n     ...\n     ...\n 
>   "[" ...\n    "{" ...\n     ...\n     ...\n    "*" ...\n 
>   ]; }{[1uj2PNSRQQWzaZRUFpuEdQ][haystack_job][3]:
>   SearchParseException[[haystack_job][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse
>   Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter":
>   {"terms": {"django_ct": ["peeldb.jobpost"]}}, "query":
>   {"query_string": {"query": "( OR (title:(python) OR
>   designation:(python)))", "default_operator": "OR", "default_field":
>   "text", "auto_generate_phrase_queries": true, "analyze_wildcard":
>   true}}}}, "from": 0, "size": 1}]]]; nested:
>   QueryParsingException[[haystack_job] Failed to parse query [( OR
>   (title:(python) OR designation:(python)))]]; nested:
>   ParseException[Cannot parse \'( OR (title:(python) OR
>   designation:(python)))\': Encountered "  "OR "" at line 1, column
>   2.\nWas expecting one of:\n     ...\n    "+" ...\n    "-" ...\n     ...\n    "(" ...\n    "*" ...\n     ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n     ...\n     ...\n 
>   "[" ...\n    "{" ...\n     ...\n     ...\n    "*" ...\n 
>   ]; nested: ParseException[Encountered "  "OR "" at line 1, column
>   2.\nWas expecting one of:\n     ...\n    "+" ...\n    "-" ...\n     ...\n    "(" ...\n    "*" ...\n     ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n     ...\n     ...\n 
>   "[" ...\n    "{" ...\n     ...\n     ...\n    "*" ...\n 
>   ]; }{[1uj2PNSRQQWzaZRUFpuEdQ][haystack_job][4]:
>   SearchParseException[[haystack_job][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse
>   Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter":
>   {"terms": {"django_ct": ["peeldb.jobpost"]}}, "query":
>   {"query_string": {"query": "( OR (title:(python) OR
>   designation:(python)))", "default_operator": "OR", "default_field":
>   "text", "auto_generate_phrase_queries": true, "analyze_wildcard":
>   true}}}}, "from": 0, "size": 1}]]]; nested:
>   QueryParsingException[[haystack_job] Failed to parse query [( OR
>   (title:(python) OR designation:(python)))]]; nested:
>   ParseException[Cannot parse \'( OR (title:(python) OR
>   designation:(python)))\': Encountered "  "OR "" at line 1, column
>   2.\nWas expecting one of:\n     ...\n    "+" ...\n    "-" ...\n     ...\n    "(" ...\n    "*" ...\n     ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n     ...\n     ...\n 
>   "[" ...\n    "{" ...\n     ...\n     ...\n    "*" ...\n 
>   ]; nested: ParseException[Encountered "  "OR "" at line 1, column
>   2.\nWas expecting one of:\n     ...\n    "+" ...\n    "-" ...\n     ...\n    "(" ...\n    "*" ...\n     ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n     ...\n     ...\n 
>   "[" ...\n    "{" ...\n     ...\n     ...\n    "*" ...\n 
>   ]; }]') Failed to query Elasticsearch using '( OR (title:(python) OR
>   designation:(python)))': TransportError(400,
>   u'SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all
>   shards failed; shardFailures
>   {[1uj2PNSRQQWzaZRUFpuEdQ][haystack_job][0]:
>   SearchParseException[[haystack_job][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse
>   Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter":
>   {"terms": {"django_ct": ["peeldb.jobpost"]}}, "query":
>   {"query_string": {"query": "( OR (title:(python) OR
>   designation:(python)))", "default_operator": "OR", "default_field":
>   "text", "auto_generate_phrase_queries": true, "analyze_wildcard":
>   true}}}}, "from": 0}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[haystack_job]
>   Failed to parse query [( OR (title:(python) OR
>   designation:(python)))]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse \'( OR
>   (title:(python) OR designation:(python)))\': Encountered "  "OR ""
>   at line 1, column 2.\nWas expecting one of:\n     ...\n    "+"
>   ...\n    "-" ...\n     ...\n    "(" ...\n    "*" ...\n
>
>    ...\n     ...\n     ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n    "[" ...\n    "{" ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n    "*" ...\n    ]; nested:
>   ParseException[Encountered "  "OR "" at line 1, column 2.\nWas
>   expecting one of:\n     ...\n    "+" ...\n    "-" ...\n
>    ...\n    "(" ...\n    "*" ...\n     ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n     ...\n     ...\n 
>   "[" ...\n    "{" ...\n     ...\n     ...\n    "*" ...\n 
>   ]; }{[1uj2PNSRQQWzaZRUFpuEdQ][haystack_job][1]:
>   SearchParseException[[haystack_job][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse
>   Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter":
>   {"terms": {"django_ct": ["peeldb.jobpost"]}}, "query":
>   {"query_string": {"query": "( OR (title:(python) OR
>   designation:(python)))", "default_operator": "OR", "default_field":
>   "text", "auto_generate_phrase_queries": true, "analyze_wildcard":
>   true}}}}, "from": 0}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[haystack_job]
>   Failed to parse query [( OR (title:(python) OR
>   designation:(python)))]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse \'( OR
>   (title:(python) OR designation:(python)))\': Encountered "  "OR ""
>   at line 1, column 2.\nWas expecting one of:\n     ...\n    "+"
>   ...\n    "-" ...\n     ...\n    "(" ...\n    "*" ...\n
>
>    ...\n     ...\n     ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n    "[" ...\n    "{" ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n    "*" ...\n    ]; nested:
>   ParseException[Encountered "  "OR "" at line 1, column 2.\nWas
>   expecting one of:\n     ...\n    "+" ...\n    "-" ...\n
>    ...\n    "(" ...\n    "*" ...\n     ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n     ...\n     ...\n 
>   "[" ...\n    "{" ...\n     ...\n     ...\n    "*" ...\n 
>   ]; }{[1uj2PNSRQQWzaZRUFpuEdQ][haystack_job][2]:
>   SearchParseException[[haystack_job][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse
>   Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter":
>   {"terms": {"django_ct": ["peeldb.jobpost"]}}, "query":
>   {"query_string": {"query": "( OR (title:(python) OR
>   designation:(python)))", "default_operator": "OR", "default_field":
>   "text", "auto_generate_phrase_queries": true, "analyze_wildcard":
>   true}}}}, "from": 0}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[haystack_job]
>   Failed to parse query [( OR (title:(python) OR
>   designation:(python)))]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse \'( OR
>   (title:(python) OR designation:(python)))\': Encountered "  "OR ""
>   at line 1, column 2.\nWas expecting one of:\n     ...\n    "+"
>   ...\n    "-" ...\n     ...\n    "(" ...\n    "*" ...\n
>
>    ...\n     ...\n     ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n    "[" ...\n    "{" ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n    "*" ...\n    ]; nested:
>   ParseException[Encountered "  "OR "" at line 1, column 2.\nWas
>   expecting one of:\n     ...\n    "+" ...\n    "-" ...\n
>    ...\n    "(" ...\n    "*" ...\n     ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n     ...\n     ...\n 
>   "[" ...\n    "{" ...\n     ...\n     ...\n    "*" ...\n 
>   ]; }{[1uj2PNSRQQWzaZRUFpuEdQ][haystack_job][3]:
>   SearchParseException[[haystack_job][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse
>   Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter":
>   {"terms": {"django_ct": ["peeldb.jobpost"]}}, "query":
>   {"query_string": {"query": "( OR (title:(python) OR
>   designation:(python)))", "default_operator": "OR", "default_field":
>   "text", "auto_generate_phrase_queries": true, "analyze_wildcard":
>   true}}}}, "from": 0}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[haystack_job]
>   Failed to parse query [( OR (title:(python) OR
>   designation:(python)))]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse \'( OR
>   (title:(python) OR designation:(python)))\': Encountered "  "OR ""
>   at line 1, column 2.\nWas expecting one of:\n     ...\n    "+"
>   ...\n    "-" ...\n     ...\n    "(" ...\n    "*" ...\n
>
>    ...\n     ...\n     ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n    "[" ...\n    "{" ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n    "*" ...\n    ]; nested:
>   ParseException[Encountered "  "OR "" at line 1, column 2.\nWas
>   expecting one of:\n     ...\n    "+" ...\n    "-" ...\n
>    ...\n    "(" ...\n    "*" ...\n     ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n     ...\n     ...\n 
>   "[" ...\n    "{" ...\n     ...\n     ...\n    "*" ...\n 
>   ]; }{[1uj2PNSRQQWzaZRUFpuEdQ][haystack_job][4]:
>   SearchParseException[[haystack_job][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse
>   Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter":
>   {"terms": {"django_ct": ["peeldb.jobpost"]}}, "query":
>   {"query_string": {"query": "( OR (title:(python) OR
>   designation:(python)))", "default_operator": "OR", "default_field":
>   "text", "auto_generate_phrase_queries": true, "analyze_wildcard":
>   true}}}}, "from": 0}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[haystack_job]
>   Failed to parse query [( OR (title:(python) OR
>   designation:(python)))]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse \'( OR
>   (title:(python) OR designation:(python)))\': Encountered "  "OR ""
>   at line 1, column 2.\nWas expecting one of:\n     ...\n    "+"
>   ...\n    "-" ...\n     ...\n    "(" ...\n    "*" ...\n
>
>    ...\n     ...\n     ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n    "[" ...\n    "{" ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n    "*" ...\n    ]; nested:
>   ParseException[Encountered "  "OR "" at line 1, column 2.\nWas
>   expecting one of:\n     ...\n    "+" ...\n    "-" ...\n
>    ...\n    "(" ...\n    "*" ...\n     ...\n    
>   ...\n     ...\n     ...\n     ...\n 
>   "[" ...\n    "{" ...\n     ...\n     ...\n    "*" ...\n 
>   ]; }]')

Comment: can you share stack trace of java exception raised by elasticsearch.

Comment: @manjit kumar edited question with java exception

Comment: @RaviGadila Did you make it work? What's the solution you have found for this?